# How to upgrade to mysql 5.6 in ubuntu 12.04

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-12.04, upgrade, mysql-5.6, mysql-5.5

I was needed to upgrade mysql 5.5 to 5.6, to avoid some issues on importing sql files.

> ERROR 1293 (HY000) at line 231: Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause

How do you upgrade it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just run the following commands:

```
apt-get -y remove mysql-server
apt-get -y autoremove
apt-get -y install software-properties-common
add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/mysql-5.6
apt-get update
apt-get -y install mysql-server
```

Comment: Don't use it, it's broken. Source: https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/mysql-5.6